# Real World U-SQL Stories

Tags: u-sql

I am doing a architectural review on the U-SQL environment and capabilities. I have read a lot, coded and implemented over the past week on a test environment. I am concerned that my file ingestion is slow when ingesting json files. 150 files 100 MB each takes over 45 minutes. Yes the json is fairly complex and nested, but let me compare that to Spark on HDInsight with 2 worker nodes, 22 minutes. Does anyone have a real-scenario (besides MS) using large amounts of data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be happy to help.   Azure Data Lake just GA'd last month, so customer case studies are still in progress.  I'd be happy to talk offline guyhay at Microsoft.com if you want to talk.